# I have created CI/CD pipeline through jenkins and deployed an application through k8s

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins, kubernetes

I have created CI/CD pipeline through jenkins and deployed an application through k8s in pod but unable to access the application in chrome or mozilla browser.

In terminal of k8s its showing an running container in pod. But unable to access the url in browser. Please assist on this.

Comment: What does your yaml file(s) look like?

Comment: did you create service to expose your pod?